# Getting Json file from remix

Tags: solidity, truffle, remix, gas, json-rpc

I have been deploying contracts on rinkeby but we are almost done to go to mainnet.

I have been comparing deployments with truffle and remix and there is a huge difference in gas uses, so I would like to deploy my contract from remix and then make the json files with the contract address to the build directory, is it possible? I can easily get the ABI from remix, but I think it doesn't have the address where the contract is deployed, right?

Comment: Am quite not sure what you want (by getting json and build directory). But, Once the contract is deployed from the remix, you can get the contract address from the transaction hash. The creator of the contract should be able to interact with the contract based on the contract code design.

Comment: when you compile with truffle it creates a build directory, with all the json files, that inside has the abi contract, bytecode, and so on, when you do the migrate on truffle, it sets all the contracts addresses, and then you just need to import that json file if you want to interact with your contract from a html or a js file...

Comment: If you are about to deploy with remix (which is manual) then you shouldn't bother about the truffle framework. Once you deployed, you can get the ABI, bytecode etc., from the remix itself, you will have to explore it though.

Comment: I know I can get it splitted, but as I have been using the Jason I want it to do it same way...